# file creation timestamp in java

Tags: java, file, timestamp

As I was fooling around the `File` methods I notices that there is no method for getting the creating timestamp of a `File`. On the other side there is one for the last modification: `lastModified()`.

Also I have read the [Basic File Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) so I am not asking how to get these timestamps. I just found it more convenient to use a syntax like:

```
file.lastModified();
```

rather than:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

with the second approach not making obvious to which file it is referring to.

Is there any reasonable explanation about that? I mean aren't they considered sine qua non to each other along with the last access timestamp. Is there any similar approach to the first one that I don't know? Is it related to the fact that a lot OS (like most Unix implementations) do not support this timestamp?

Comment: I think that anwers are opinion-based, so this may get closed. - (1) OS file metadata varies considerably, between OSs and with time. (2) Doing it all with JDK 1.0 would have been a gargantuan task. (3) I suppose you can write a class that obtains all "interesting" attributes, hiding some differences between File and whatever jav.nio.files provides.

Comment: I do not agree about opinion-based part. The only part is that could be considered opinion-based is the last question.

Comment: Re "reasonable explanation": One man's reason is another man's folly. ;-) -- Not sure whether you can find any rationale by Gosling and Co. about what should be part of 1.0. Anything else is guesswork. -- Are you interested in History? -- I don't think you have missed anything in the 1.7 or later API.